# Select, move and deselect a card from Solitaire game pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to select a card with the mouse (the card changes to another image of a card with orange edges), move it (or not) and later deselect the card clicking again, returning it to the original image of the card (without orange edges).
I made the two first steps, but I can't find a way to deselect the card.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button==1 and mouse_rect.colliderect(card_rect):
            card = pygame.image.load("1c2.png").convert_alpha()
            card = pygame.transform.scale(card, (99, 100))

        if event.button == 1 and not mouse_rect.colliderect(card_rect):
            n = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x = n[0]
            y = n[1]
            card_rect.centerx = x
            card_rect.centery = y
            
        if event.button==1 and mouse_rect.colliderect(card_rect) and card_rect.width==99:
            card = pygame.image.load("1c.png").convert_alpha()
            card = pygame.transform.scale(card, (100, 100))
```

Original image:1c.png
Image selected (with orange edges):1c2.png

I try to change a little the width of the card when you select it, and after using that in the last conditional that you can see above.
I also tried (in the last conditional too):

```
         if event.button==1 and mouse_rect.colliderect(card_rect) and card==pygame.image.load("1c2.png").convert_alpha():
            card = pygame.image.load("1c.png").convert_alpha()
            card = pygame.transform.scale(card, (100, 100))
```

What can I do to fix it?
Thanks!

Wrong result: The card stays at the selected image (card with orange borders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not load  the images in the application loop. Load the images before the application loop. Use a Boolean variable (`card_selected`) to indicate if the map is selected. Invert the state when clicking on the card (`card_selected = not card_selected`):

```py
card_1 = pygame.image.load("1c.png").convert_alpha()
card_1 = pygame.transform.scale(card_1, (100, 100))
card_2 = pygame.image.load("1c2.png").convert_alpha()
card_2 = pygame.transform.scale(card_2, (100, 100))
card = card_1
card_selected = False

# [...]

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1 and card_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                card_selected = not card_selected
                card = card_2 if card_selected else card_1

    # [...]

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Do not forget to clear the display in every frame. The entire scene must be redrawn in each frame.